# How to acces to parent data in child component

Tags: knockout.js, components, viewmodel

```js
var ParentModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.cols = [
     {name:'id',type:'int'},
     {name:'name',type:'varchar'},
     {name:'desc',type:'text'}
  ];
  this.rows = [
     {id:1,name:'Peter',desc:'sometext'},
     {id:2,name:'Jack',desc:'sometext'},
     {id:3,name:'Mary',desc:'sometext'}
  ];
  this.current = ko.observable();
  this.edit = function(e){
    self.current(e);
  }
}

ko.components.register('form-control', {
  
  viewModel: function(params) {
        // how i get parent current data from inside component?
    },
  template: '<input data-bind="value: text" />'
});
    

ko.applyBindings(new ParentModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <!--ko foreach: cols-->
            <th data-bind="text: name"></th>
            <!--/ko-->
            <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <!--ko foreach: rows-->
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $index"></td>
            <!--ko foreach: $parent.cols-->
            <td data-bind="text:$parent[name]"></td>
            <!--/ko-->
            <td>
                <button data-bind="click: $parent.edit">Edit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--/ko-->
      </tbody>
    </table>

<span data-bind="text:JSON.stringify(current())"></span>

<form>
   <form-control params="data-field: 'id'"></form-control>
</form>
```

I want to render fields/columns current row data depend on its datatype automatically. What should I do? please show me the way.

If the form content should be load with ajax call, what is difference? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to pass param to form-control:

```
<form>
   <form-control params="data-field: 'id', current: current"></form-control>
</form>
```

And use it in your component:

```
ko.components.register('form-control', {

  viewModel: function(params) {
      this.current = params.current;
  },
  template: '<input data-bind="value: current().name" />'
});
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtoLn37d/)

Comment: Is there any way to nobody passing parameters in using component? If we have many fields in this forms. It make we repeat themselves. I forgot, thank your answer.

Comment: You can pass reference to the whole model `model: $data` and use it  `viewModel: function(params) { return params.model;  }`

Comment: Another option would be sharing the instance of your parent viewmodel between all the form-control components see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xtoLn37d/1/

Comment: I have a problem when I using requirejs to load component on demand. With form-control above. I want to call Ajax to get dynamic template, but the Ajax call is asynchronous and return component object got no template. How make it works correctly?

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html

Comment: so.. this isn't really a good answer. If in my component mark-up, I make use of a `with` binding or a `foreach`, how do I pop back up to reference something at the component level?